# Update label from mainform class with backgroundworker from another class

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have two classes.

```
Public Class MainForm

     Private Project As clsProject


Private Sub btnDo_Click
   ...
   Backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub
 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork


    Project = New clsProject


End Sub
```

and two methods inside MainForm

```
 Public Shared Sub setLabelTxt(ByVal text As String, ByVal lbl As Label)
    If lbl.InvokeRequired Then
        lbl.Invoke(New setLabelTxtInvoker(AddressOf setLabelTxt), text, lbl)
    Else
        lbl.Text = text
    End If
End Sub
Public Delegate Sub setLabelTxtInvoker(ByVal text As String, ByVal lbl As Label)
end class
```

I want to update the labels of MainForm from the clsProject constructor.

```
 MainForm.setLabelTxt("Getting prsadasdasdasdasdry..", MainForm.lblProgress)
```

but it does not update them.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot execute any action on GUI-elements from the `BackgroundWorker` directly. One way to "overcome" that is by forcing the given actions to be performed from the main thread via `Me.Invoke`; but this is not the ideal proceeding. Additionally, your code mixes up main form and external class (+ shared/non-shared objects) what makes the whole structure not too solid.

A for-sure working solution is relying on the specific BGW methods for dealing with GUI elements; for example: `ProgressChanged Event`. Sample code:

```
Public Class MainForm
    Private Project As clsProject
    Public Shared bgw As System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        bgw = BackgroundWorker1 'Required as far as you want to called it from a Shared method

        BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        Project = New clsProject
    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub setLabelTxt(ByVal text As String)
        bgw.ReportProgress(0, text) 'You can write any int as first argument as far as will not be used anyway
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
        Me.Label1.Text = e.UserState 'You can access the given GUI-element directly
        Me.Label1.Update()
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class clsProject
    Public Sub New()
        MainForm.setLabelTxt("Getting prsadasdasdasdasdry..")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: your solution uses the capabilities of bw and presented me a new way of working with it. thank you very much for your time. My label now is updated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using the global `MainForm` instance to access the label in a background thread here:

```
Public Class clsProject
    Public Sub New()
        ' When accessing MainForm.Label1 on the next line, it causes an exception
        MainForm.setLabelTxt("HERE!", MainForm.Label1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

It's OK to call `MainForm.setLabelTxt`, since that is a shared method, so it's not going through the global instance to call it.  But, when you access the `Label1` property, that's utilizing VB.NET's trickery to access the global instance of the form.  Using the form through that auto-global-instance variable (which always shares the same name as the type) is apparently not allowed in non-UI threads.  When you do so, it throws an `InvalidOperationException`, with the following error message:

> An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: ActiveX control '8856f961-340a-11d0-a96b-00c04fd705a2' cannot be instantiated because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.

I'm guessing that the reason you are not seeing the error is because you are catching the exception somewhere and you are simply ignoring it.  If you stop using that global instance variable, the error goes away and it works.  For instance, if you change the constructor to this:

```
Public Class clsProject
    Public Sub New(f As MainForm)
        ' The next line works because it doesn't use the global MainForm instance variable
        MainForm.setLabelTxt("HERE!", f.Label1)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, in your `MainForm`, you would have to call it like this:

```
Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    Project = New clsProject(Me)   ' Must pass Me
End Sub
```

Using the global instance from the background thread is not allowed, but when we use the same label from the background thread, without going through that global variable it works.

So it's clear that you cannot use the global `MainForm` variable from a background thread, but what may not be clear is that it's a bad idea to use it ever.  First, it's confusing because it shares the same name as the `MainForm` type.  More importantly, though, it is a global variable, and global state of any kind is almost always bad practice, if it can be avoided.

While the above example does solve the problem, it's still a pretty poor way of doing it.  A better option would be to pass the `setLabelTxt` method to the `clsProject` object or even better have the `clsProject` simply raise an event when the label needs to be changed.  Then, the `MainForm` can simply listen for those events and handle them when they happen.  Ultimately, that `clsProject` class is probably some sort of business class which shouldn't be doing any kind of UI work anyway.

Comment: Indeed it is a bussiness class but how else could I show information to the user about whats going on? Thank you for the careful explanation you provided me with and I appreciate the advice. The solution presented below by varocabras does the job without passing parameters between the classes in the constructor and uses the capabilities built in the backgroundworker. All in all, I have learned something new, thank you for that!

Comment: As I said, my recommendation would be to simply have your business classes, if necessary, raise events to update the status while they are processing.  Then each consumer of the business class can update the user in different ways.  A console app may want to handle the status updated event by writing a line to the console, whereas a service may want to write it to a trace log or just ignore the event entirely, etc.  Yes, varocabras did provide a working solution, but it only works with one instance of the main form at a time and it relies on global state.

Comment: I will have to write this down. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Me.Invoke(...)
```

instead of `lbl.Invoke(...`. I had to do this. This is my implementation:

```
Delegate Sub SetTextDelegate(ByVal args As String)

Private Sub SetTextBoxInfo(ByVal txt As String)
    If txtInfo.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim md As New SetTextDelegate(AddressOf SetTextBoxInfo)
        Me.Invoke(md, txt)
    Else
        txtInfo.Text = txt
    End If
End Sub
```

And this worked for me.

Comment: I'll try your implementation and let you know the result. I'll be away now for an hour as I got a meeting :)

Comment: idk if it will solve your problem, since looks like it comes from executing it from another form and interacting with the BackgroundWorker. I will try a solution later.

Comment: the clsProject class is not another Form. I have just one form. I'll try now

Comment: moreover, in the clsProject, the txtInfo.InvokeRequired is false. It always takes the Else branch and the label is not updated.

Comment: You should replace `txtInfo` for your label. `txtInfo` was my textbox. But the error may come from the problems exposed in the other answers.

Comment: Yes. I used txtInfo to refer to your example. I used lblProgress in my program. Thank you for your time. The solution presented by varocarbas solved the issue